# Why is there a capacitor in parallel with this fan? What is the benefit?

Tags: capacitor, dc, fan

[image: proportional fan speed controller]
<sub>(source: [electronicdesign.com](http://electronicdesign.com/Content/UserStorage/17928/62767-fig1.jpg))</sub>

I understand that capacitors store charge, however this circuit is supposed to be a proportional controller. I just dont see why the capacitor is needed. Perhaps to reduce oscillation?

Answer (score 10):

The capacitor is there to reduce radio emissions.  Things have to be switched as a function of rotation angle to make most motors run.  Those switching transients can cause voltage spikes, which can emit RF interence.  The capacitor shorts out the high frequencies and keeps their currents local.  It will also slow down transient edges that the FET sees.  Too high a dV/dt on the drain of the FET can cause problems.

Answer (score 5):

Capacitors pass AC current and block DC current.<sup>*</sup>

The fan is an inductive device - it will be causing an AC waveform to be induced over the DC voltage.

The capacitor is basically providing a low resistance path (short circuit) for that AC signal so it doesn't interfere with other parts of the circuitry.

<sub><sup>*</sup>depending on frequency, resistance, filter effects, etc.</sub>

Comment: The power supply is DC. So the fan will have an AC waveform regardless, due to it being an inductive device?

Comment: Yes.  Magnets, coils and spinniness makes voltages.

Comment: The main thing is that DC motors always require commutation of some kind. Whether this is done by old fashioned carbon brushes on a commutator ring, or hall-effect driven FETS, AC is produced internal to the motor.